# Null Pointer Exception in java servlets pages

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

Im very beginner in Java servlets... i have tried to connect servlet with database but `NullPointerException`

I tried to resolve this problem ,but no luck...

Error is

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     JDBCServlet.service(JDBCServlet.java:(42)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.DriverManager;//1
import java.sql.Connection;//2
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;//3
import java.sql.ResultSet;//4

public class JDBCServlet extends HttpServlet {
    Connection con;
     Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    String sql;

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("JDBC Servlet Invoked");

        //1st step: load JDBC MySql Drivers
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Drivers Loaded");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //2nd Step: create a connection
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webtech1", "root", "123456");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String sql = "select * from user";
        try {
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next()){

                System.out.println(rs.getInt("id"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("firstName"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("lastName"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("email"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("password"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("createdate"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

---

Comment: I guess the line no 42 is `st = con.createStatement();`, Did you check STDOUT for any DB Connection error? If yes what is the error?

Comment: I guess your connection object is null. CheckList -> 1) Is your driver loaded? 2) Can you debug and find if you are able to get connection object as not null?

Comment: yes error in this line..st = con.createStatement();  but don't know why... db connection is working... i have tested it ....

Comment: 1 driver loaded fine..  error in just st = con.createStatement();  in this line.. before this line all code worked...

Answer (score 0):

Please put null checks on your `con,st,rs` objects. And also double check your mysql connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialised `String sql` twice. One as a property and one as a local variable i.e.

```
String sql = "select * from user";
```

Later, you are calling `sql` (an instance variable) which is indeed of `null` value, which causes [null pointer exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html). You just need to remove `String` declaration from the body of your `service` method.

Comment: After removing String from Services method Area still same error i have find..

Comment: @Asad Sorry, I'm at loss then. Maybe you have not added appropriate MySql `.jar` file to the build path.